# Conditionally render an Astro component based on page type query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, astrojs

I am using [Astro](https://astro.build), GraphQL ([Apollo Client)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/), Typescript and React.

In my dynamic route: `[...slug].astro` file I need to conditionally render a certain Astro component.

I managed to that with:

```
 {data.page.type === 'PageOneType' && <PageOne />}
 {data.page.type === 'PageTwoType' && <PageTwo />}
```

Can I somehow make this more dynamic, so I don't have to add it static like above in case there are more page types in the feature?

Or do I need to pull in React for this?

Update:
`PageOne` and `PageTwo` components will have different components and data. The data they get from a page query with different fragments:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export default gql`
  query Page($target: String!) {
    page(target: $target) {
      type
      content {
        ... on PageOne {
          id
          title
        }
        ... on PageTwo {
          id
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: What do these PageOne, PageTwo components consist of? If they're not very different, consider just passing props (from your page data) to a single Page component for example.

Comment: Could the query not be dynamic? So depending on the page type, e.g. for page one, the query only runs `on PageOne`.

And then in the Astro Page component, you could use [conditional rendering](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-syntax/#dynamic-html) based on the data passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map with a string key and the component as the value.

```
const PageOne: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>Page One</div>;
};

const PageTwo: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>Page Two</div>;
};

const PageThree: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>Page Three</div>;
};

const PageMap: Record<string, React.FC> = {
  PageOneType: PageOne,
  PageTwoType: PageTwo,
  PageThreeType: PageThree
};

const Main: React.FC = () => {
  const Component = PageMap["PageOneType"];
  return <Component />;
};
```

Comment: I was assuming React was in play since this page: https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#the-component-script mentions that "You can use the component script to write any JavaScript code that you need to render your template. This can include: ... importing other framework components, like React".